# SVG CSS animation after hover off

Tags: css, svg

I tried several ways to svg animation, but i can't do finish animation after hover off. I have seen some hints on stackoverflow, but in my situation it does not work. In my example I have few options animations in keyframes.

https://codepen.io/GuyDiamond/pen/QBpQze

```
<rect x="0" y="5" width="100" height="100" fill="red" />
<path id="heart" class="heart" d="M 10,30 A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30 A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30 Q 90,60 50,90 Q 10,60 10,30 z" fill="#fff"/>   



<style type="text/css">
    svg:hover .heart {
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;                        
        animation-duration: 4s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;            
        animation-name: rotation;
        transition: .5s; 
        animation-direction: normal;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;                    
    }    

    @keyframes rotation {        
        50% {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        opacity:0;        
        }

        60% {                
        transform: translate(100px, 0);                
        opacity:0;       
        }

        100% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
        opacity:1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you want with pure CSS. You need to use JS.

Here's one way, using the `animationiteration` event, which fires each time the animation loop ends.

```js
// Get the SVG DOM object
var mysvg = document.getElementById("mysvg");
var running = false;

// On hover add the "run" class, which makes the animation run
mysvg.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(evt) {
  evt.target.classList.add("run");
  running = true;
});

// On mouse out, arrange to remove the "run" class when the animation loop ends
mysvg.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(evt) {
  running = false;
});

// When animation loop ends, remove the "run" class if we no longer want to continue running
mysvg.addEventListener("animationiteration", function(evt) {
  if (!running) {
    evt.target.ownerSVGElement.classList.remove("run");
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg id="mysvg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-30 0 250 500" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.41421;">
  
    <rect x="0" y="5" width="100" height="100" fill="red" />
    <path id="heart" class="heart" d="M 10,30 A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30 A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30 Q 90,60 50,90 Q 10,60 10,30 z" fill="#fff"/>   



    <style type="text/css">
      
        svg .heart {
        } 
        .run .heart {
            animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;                        
            animation-duration: 4s;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;            
            animation-name: rotation;        
            animation-direction: normal;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;                    
        }    

        @keyframes rotation {        
            50% {
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
            opacity:0;        
            }

            60% {                
            transform: translate(100px, 0);                
            opacity:0;       
            }

            100% {
            transform: translate(0, 0);
            opacity:1;
            }
        }  
  </style>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: As I thought. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You mean the animation ends suddenly? That's because you've defined the transition in the hover so as soon as the hover ends there's no active transition any more.

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-30 0 250 500" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:1.41421;">
  
    <rect x="0" y="5" width="100" height="100" fill="red" />
    <path id="heart" class="heart" d="M 10,30 A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30 A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30 Q 90,60 50,90 Q 10,60 10,30 z" fill="#fff"/>   



    <style type="text/css">
        svg .heart {
            transition: .5s; 
           
        }    
        svg:hover .heart {
            animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;                        
            animation-duration: 4s;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;            
            animation-name: rotation;
            animation-direction: normal;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;                 }    

        @keyframes rotation {        
            50% {
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
            opacity:0;        
            }

            60% {                
            transform: translate(100px, 0);                
            opacity:0;       
            }

            100% {
            transform: translate(0, 0);
            opacity:1;
            }
        }  
  </style>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, the animation ends abruptly, but I want the animation to go to the last keyframe (or back to the first) and then stop.

Comment: That's what my answer does, no?

Comment: In response, what you give me when the heart is in the back of the red square, after hover off, heart back to the front quickly.  Can it do it more smoothly along the path set in keyframes?

Comment: I think you'll have to be clearer. I don't really understand.

Comment: I'm sorry as I wrote it not clearly. When i :hover out, the animation reset - but I want it to continue till the end.

Comment: @RobertLongson it seems what he's asking for is that the animation reverses on hover off until it reaches the starting point.

Personally, this solution works great for me

Answer (score 0):

By changing the animation-play-state on hover I think it could work
https://codepen.io/dok/pen/ZjKGRE

```
        svg #heart {
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;                        
        animation-duration: 4s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;            
        animation-name: rotation;        
        animation-direction: normal;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;    
        animation-play-state: paused;
    } 
  svg .heart:hover #heart {
    animation-play-state: running;
  }
```

Comment: MY intention is animation continue till the end, after hover off. As shown above by Paul LeBeau.